# unable to Write list to a file in python, always ending up in retaining only last element

Tags: python, list

**Trying to write list to a file, but ending up in returning only last element in the file.**

```
file_Error_list=[]

with open(csv_file, "r") as my_input_file:
        csv_dict_reader = DictReader(my_input_file)
        for row in csv_dict_reader:
             file_Error_list = (row['ERROR'])    
             print file_Error_list   ## This is printing all the elements in the list that i am reading from .csv file




with open(txt_file, "a") as my_output_file:
    #Trial_4 my_output_file.write(file_Error_list)   
  
    for item in file_Error_list:
         #Trial_1 my_output_file.write(item)
         #Trial_2 my_output_file.write("%s \n" %item)
         #Trial_3 my_output_file.write(file_Error_list)
         #Trial_5 below
         my_output_file.write("\n".join(item))  # This will write only last element in the list to the file



my_output_file.close()    
my_input_file.close()
```

**I also tried with 'w'. but all the results are same, just getting the last element written to the file but not the whole list**

Please suggest.

Comment: Can you post an example of `file_Error_list` please?

Comment: @Daniil, thanks for the response. the content inside the list is large set of string (approx 100 characters each)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be replacing `file_Error_list`  each time in your read loop. Instead append the row values

Replace

```
 file_Error_list = (row['ERROR'])
```

with

```
 file_Error_list.append(row['ERROR'])
```